# Run i3lock with another user's password

Tags: users, i3

I am trying to run `i3lock` which relies on the `USER` variable for the password to unlock the computer. I am running this on Fedora 24.

I need this to be in a shell script because it is being executed by `acpid`.

```
#!/bin/sh
export USER=myusername
i3lock
```

But the `USER` variable is still set to the root. How can I set this environment variable from the shell script?

Comment: The reason you're not receiving an answer is because there is false information in your question.  `export USER=myusername` will **most definitely** set the `USER` variable as specified, but it will not change the user under which the commands are run.  I don't understand what you're actually trying to do so that makes it difficult to give you good suggestions too.

Comment: Tip: ask about [what you want to do](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/296747/2) rather than [focusing on an attempt to solve the problem that may well turn out to have no chance of helping](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we look at the [source](https://github.com/i3/i3lock/blob/master/i3lock.c) for (a version of) i3lock, we can see it determines the user whose password is required by doing `getuid()`. So setting the environment variable `USER` has no effect, and you will need to su or sudo as that user instead.